# Running a Linux VM in Proxmox in "recovery mode"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, proxmox

I have a VM (Ubuntu 20.04) that deletes all data on startup due to a misconfigured service that runs on boot. I have a backup of the VM, but after restoration I cannot start it without losing any data.

My hosting provider provides me with a Proxmox user interface, so I have a root console to access the VM while it boots. But I found no way to prevent the kernel of the VM to load the service that breaks everything.

Is there any way to boot the VM without starting the broken service that deletes all data?

Answer (score 0):

While I have not found a direct answer to my question, I was able to restore my VM another way: Through Proxmox, I was able to start another operating system (a recovery OS) and mount my hard drive in there. That way I was able to make the necessary changes on my partition to reboot into the restored VM.